# Can Picasa export directly to a chosen folder instead of subfolder?

Tags: picasa

When I attempt to export pictures in Picasa, it forces me to always export to a subfolder of my chosen folder. Example:

Export Picture > Choose C:\picasaexports\

In the export window, it shows (by default) that it will export to

```
C:\picasaexport\2012-07-07 (todays date)
```

I can type in anything I want instead of the date. If I leave it blank the subfolder name is `export`. It doesn't seem possible to export DIRECTLY to whatever folder you select. The only workaround (using the example above) would be to choose your export folder as `C:\` and then manually type in `picasaexport` as the subfolder name. Seems stupid, especially if your folder has a really long name cause you gotta type it out...

Is there a better way to get around this problem?